# Convert every git commit into separate folder

Tags: git

I have a project that I completed in several discrete steps, each building off each other.

My commit history looks like this:

`p1 -> p2 -> ... -> pn`

Each part functions just fine on its own, and I would like to export each step of the project as a self-contained unit. For example:

```
project/
  p1/
  p2/
  ...
  pn/
```

Where each directory `p` contains all files and folders in the branch when it was committed (files which were present in `p1` and remained unchanged through `pn` should be redundantly included in each directory).
How do I convert each individual commit into its own folder?

Comment: I can see, I think, why one would want to do this. Suppose you develop an _example_ where each commit is a successive _state_ in the development of the example. Now you want to checkout each state separately for teaching purposes: Here is the project during step one, here is the project during step two, and so on. Is that the sort of thing you're doing? If so, how many commits are we talking about? I can readily imagine just doing this "by hand" if there are not too many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do using tar or zip to un-archive archives:

1. Use `git rev-list` to generate the list of hash IDs for each commit.
2. Use `git archive` to turn each commit snapshot into an archive.
3. Use `tar` or `unzip` to turn each archive into a source-tree in a numbered `p/` folder.

In shell script (bash, more or less), this is:

```
step=1
git rev-list --reverse --topo-order $last |
while read rev; do
    mkdir /path/to/p$step
    git archive $rev | tar -C /path/to/p$step -xf -
    : $((step+=1))
done
```

(note: the above is untested).

Edit to mention forgotten part: set `last` above to the *last* commit you want exported.  Use a raw hash ID if you like, or the branch name if you like.  A Git branch name simply names the *last* commit in the branch (always, by definition).  The loop automatically numbers the extracted folders sequentially according to the result of the rev-list, so if starting at the last commit and working backwards counts 5000 commits, you'll get 5000 folders, numbered starting from 1 (as requested).

Note that each commit *is* the snapshot you want—commits do not hold changes, they hold snapshots—but a commit in a Git repository has its files stored in a special, read-only, Git-only archive format, compressed so that *identical* files are immediately de-duplicated, and *similar* files eventually (though not immediately) take very little space.  You wanted each snapshot as ordinary files.  That means you have to get Git to *extract* them.

The `git checkout` command does exactly that: it *extracts files*.  But it does too much: it does that into one *work-tree*, along with maintaining information so that a `git commit` or another `git checkout` can be done later.  If you do another `git checkout`, Git has all *those* files removed-and-replaced with the ones from the *next* commit you check out.  So `git checkout` isn't the expand-snapshot-to-normal-files command we want.

(Neither is `git archive`, really, but once we turn the snapshot into a standard tar or zip archive, we can use the standard tar or unzip tool to extract the files somewhere that's *not* the work-tree, where those files are safe from accidental clobbering by another `git checkout`.)

Answer (score 4):

Using a script, you can get all the commit hashes, and for each commit, clone the repository and checkout to the desired commit:

```sh
#/bin/bash

commits=$(git log --pretty=format:"%h")
dest=/path/to/the/destination/folder
repo=git@github.com:username/repository.git

for commit in $commits; do
    echo $commit
    git clone -q $repo $dest/$commit
    cd $dest/$commit
    git checkout -q $commit
done
```

Run this script in your repository folder.